# Is it possible to make a mouse accelerate like it did in Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse

15 year Windows guy here, slowly going full Mac on everything and enjoying it.

But there's one thing that's killing me: the USB mouse acceleration curve in Snow Leopard drives me crazy. I've looked at utilities that claim to change it, but I haven't found anything that works (thanks Apple for removing the mouse acceleration curve function). I really want my mouse to move like it did in Windows.

What I have discovered is that different mice seem to have slightly different acceleration (or I'm going insane). I use a cheap Dell optical mouse at work that's fairly similar to what I'm used to in Windows. But my Razer Imperator at home, despite costing a fortune, moves like molasses through OS X.

I've tried the Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad and have been unsatisfied with both.

Is this actually an issue? I may be very well be imagining it. Have any other ex-Windows guys experienced this?

Comment: Yes, I use a newer Logitech mouse and no matter what I do I can't replicate the same motion/acceleration/speed I'm used to in Windows. I do think this is a function of the driver/utility from Logitech though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No, unless you buy a specific mouse

The option to define custom mouse acceleration curves *was* present in OS X 10.4, but apple simplified it in 10.5, and removed it entirely in 10.6.

[Mouse Curve](http://triq.net/articles/mouse-curve-app-mac-os-x) is a supposedly forthcoming pref-pane that completely replaces the OS X mouse HID kext. However, development is really slow, or stalled.

Personally, I have poked about a bit in the kernel myself, but am unfamiliar with kernel programming. Fixing the mouse acceleration on OS X will at minimum require a custom kext, which is non-trivial to code.

The option that *is* out there is to buy a Microsoft mouse, and use it on OS X. Microsoft has released [custom drivers](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/drivers/intellipointandintellitypepro.html) for their mice that [mimic the mouse behavior on windows](http://www.dreamplusstudio.com/apple/microsoft-arc-mouse-intellipoint-software-finally-disabled-mac-osx-mouse-acceleration).

---

Essentially, the windows "Enhance Pointer Precision" option applies *linear velocity-based acceleration* to the mouse movements, e.g. the distance moved is proportional to the *speed* the mouse moves. Think of it as basically having the DPI of the mouse inversely proportional to the mouse's speed.

OS X on the other hand, has a *stepped* acceleration curve, where the mouse moves at one DPI when slow, and another when moved faster then a threshold.

There are pref-panes that let you *disable* OS X's acceleration curve, but none that allow you to substitute windows.

As far as I can tell (and this is opinion), this curve is optimized for *trackpads*. In my opinion, it is more then useless for mice (using a mac mouse actually damaged my mousing efficacy on windows, which really affects my work (CAD Stuff)).

Personally, I have entirely dispensed with the idea of using a mouse on OS X, and ust bought a Magic Trackpad.

Comment: Up vote for magic trackpad or Microsoft mouse options. The only ways to go IMHO.

Comment: That website seems to recommend the Arc mouse. Is it possible to use another Microsoft mouse with that same Intellipoint software?

Comment: I *think* the intellipoint drivers work with any (or most) microsoft mice.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, using the command line of iMouseFix**

The command line version of [mousefix/iMouseFix](https://github.com/infowolfe/iMouseFix) is working for me on 10.6 with the Apple MagicMouse (some of the other suggested solutions don't work for the MagicMouse). I can quickly move the mouse between displays, but also do fine work with a setting of 8.

```
/Application/mousefix/mousefix 8
```

I have added the following to my .profile as they suggest in the [README](https://github.com/infowolfe/iMouseFix/blob/master/README)

FYI, The binary download is mousefix.tbz2 at http://code.google.com/p/mousefix-10-6/downloads/list.

Also see the similar question at superuser - https://superuser.com/a/446200/66255

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a Razer DeathAdder, and after a LOT of tweaking in Razer's own driver panel, it works beautifully with my Mac.

You should definitely check out http://www.razersupport.com/ and download the Mac driver.

Different mice respond differently to begin with, and send that information back to the OS in any number of different resolutions. A gaming mouse especially is going to be sending MUCH different information back to your system than a typical desktop mouse. Razer's driver should have an acceleration slider that you can tweak to your liking, and should also be able to process that device's input in a way that makes more sense to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mouse Acceleration Preference Pane](http://triq.net/software/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x).

Comment: Tried that one. It's no good without the ability to set curves.

Answer (score 0):

[a solution i posted in another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45863/1904) should help.

No third party software required.

Answer (score 0):

There may be news about a prospective mouse fix for Mac OS X: [Project SmoothMouse](http://d43.me/blog/1410/looking-for-brains/).

From the developer’s website (emphasis mine):

> The current development phase is “pre-alpha”. The foundation is done
>   for the most part, and we’re **now looking to fix the bugs** and extend
>   the functionality. [On Sept 10, 2012] we started the first round of
>   private testing among the developers.

Comment: This is pre-alpha software. Have you found it to be reliable under any Mac OS version?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.