# How can I really turn off mouse cursor acceleration in macOS 14.0 (Sonoma)

Tags: macos, mouse

I want to disable mouse cursor acceleration, but the method described in [How to permanently disable mouse acceleration (MacOS Monterey)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439131/how-to-permanently-disable-mouse-acceleration-macos-monterey) (
`defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1`) no longer works in Sonoma.

But when I move my mouse from a fixed point A to fixed point B on my mouse mat, the mouse cursor moves on a much shorter distance when I move slowly from A to B than when I move fast from A to B, so it proves acceleration is NOT turned off.

And I've also tried other values from 0 to 3, which clearly don't turn off mouse acceleration.

I've also browsed this old topic which refers only to deprecated solutions :
[Disable mouse acceleration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7201/disable-mouse-acceleration)

P.S. : I'm using a "Razer Viper mini" if there is a specific solution

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that Razer mouse acceleration exhibited this same issue in Windows and Linux as well.  Try connecting a cheap, generic mouse and test acceleration with that first to determine if the setting is in fact being disabled

Answer (score 7):

As of macOS 14.0 Sonoma, mouse acceleration can be disabled in *System Settings > Mouse > Advanced...*

[image: macOS Sonoma Mouse Acceleration Settings]

You can also script the same change with `defaults`:

```sh
# When linear, acceleration is off
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.linear -bool YES
```

For older versions of macOS, [LinearMouse](https://linearmouse.app/) can be used to disable mouse acceleration.

Comment: To be mentioned: macOS Sonoma will be available in July as a public beta and the official release will be in Fall 2023. You must have a developer account to get macOS Sonoma now (it was released on June 5th as a developer beta).